# Dropzone JS throws "undefined" when adding "error event"

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropzone.js

My Dropzone is limited to 2 Files ( maxFiles: 2). If the user drags a new File into the Dropzone, the maxfileexceeds event shows an error.

```
myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
        alert("no more files accepted");
        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
    })
```

But:
If I add the "error event"..

```
myDropzone.on("error", function(file, errormessage, response){
        alert(response.message);
    })
```

to get a response if something fails, Dropzone alerts an "undefined".
The params on the error event should be correct..
Qoute(DropzoneJS homepage):

> error: An error occured. Receives the errorMessage as second parameter and if the error was due to the XMLHttpRequest the xhr object as third.

So the first param is the file, second an errormessage (according to the author) and the 3rd param is a error which comes from the server.

The error response on the server looks like this:

```
$response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'unknown error occured');

header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$response["message"] = $message;
exit (json_encode($response));
```

so why does Dropzone give me an "undefined" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third parameter is an `XHR` object not the response. Please try this:

```
myDropzone.on("error", function(file, errormessage, xhr){
    if(xhr) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(response.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your very fast answer! it works now. thought it would be enough just to pass the json object

Comment: You are welcome! If this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).